# Download image from URL on page load using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I want when page load my image must be downloaded based on URL! But my following code is not working please help!

**Code:**

```js
function myFunction() { 
   
  var link = document.createElement('a');
link.href = 'https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMTAxMGRmODYtM2NkYS00ZGRlLWE1MWItYjI1MzIwNjQwN2RiXkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyMTMxODk2OTU@._V1_SX300.jpg';
link.download = 'Download.jpg';
document.body.appendChild(link);
link.click();
document.body.removeChild(link);

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body onload="myFunction()">


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "not working" — What do you expect to happen? What actually happens?

Comment: I want the image should be downloaded on page load.

Comment: What do you mean by "download"? Si you want it to be fetched by the browser and shown in the page? (If so, why to use JavaScript instead of an img tag) or do you want the image to download as a file?

Comment: I want the image to download as a file on page load!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
function downloadImage(url, name){
      fetch(url)
        .then(resp => resp.blob())
        .then(blob => {
            const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
            const a = document.createElement('a');
            a.style.display = 'none';
            a.href = url;
            // the filename you want
            a.download = name;
            document.body.appendChild(a);
            a.click();
            window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
        })
        .catch(() => alert('An error sorry'));
}
```

```html
<button onclick="downloadImage('https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMTAxMGRmODYtM2NkYS00ZGRlLWE1MWItYjI1MzIwNjQwN2RiXkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyMTMxODk2OTU@._V1_SX300.jpg', 'Download.jpg')" >DOWNLOAD</button>

<body onload="downloadImage('https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMTAxMGRmODYtM2NkYS00ZGRlLWE1MWItYjI1MzIwNjQwN2RiXkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyMTMxODk2OTU@._V1_SX300.jpg', 'Download.jpg')">
```

NOTE: I am not sure why the "Run Code Snippet" is not working so please check the solution in code pen https://codepen.io/Gopi-Veeramani/pen/KKyzoJL